# ARIS BPM tool - usage and advantanges

Tags: modeling

How is your organization benefiting from the usage of ARIS bpm designer tool (licensed version features)?

I see a few posts on this site related to modeling being done using ARIS Express free edition. But I am curious to know the added benefit apart from creating a solid repository and methodology for modelling information.

What are the tool's pro's and cons?

Comment: ARIS is a tool for modeling business processes aimed at business users (not developers). I doubt you will find lots of users with ARIS experience here, the question seems slightly out-of-topic.

Comment: Architects from IT are involved in this activity as well. Hoping to get some feedback from them on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0xA3 might be right that this question is slightly off-topic here. Still, lets try to give a short answer:

Using a tool such as ARIS is not about just documenting your processes. This is just the first step. Take those models and analyse them. Try to reveal information, which you were not aware of before. There are many different techniques how to work with models, e.g. simulation and process cost calculation. Also, you can use ARIS' internal scripting engine to create your own custom analysis.

The point is not in just documenting, but on working with those models to solve problems.

May we invite you to post your question to [ARIS Community](http://www.ariscommunity.com/) and discuss it with other ARIS users?